# How to set custom font for UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller, custom-font

Able to set font for alert title and alert message but not for the Ok alert button.

Want to set the font for the Ok also, Thanks in advance.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString(title, comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString(newErrorMessage, comment: "") , preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alertController.view.tintColor = UIConfiguration.DarkGreen!
            let titleFont = LanguageManager.boldFont(size: 17.0)
            let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString(title, comment: ""), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: titleFont])
            alertController.setValue(attributedTitle, forKey: "attributedTitle")
            let messageFont = LanguageManager.regularFont(size: 12.0)
            let attributedMessage = NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString(newErrorMessage, comment: ""), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: messageFont])
            alertController.setValue(attributedMessage, forKey: "attributedMessage")
            
            //Unable to set the font for OK button.
            let okFont = LanguageManager.boldFont(size: 16.0)
            let attributedOk = NSAttributedString(string: NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: ""), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: okFont])
            alertController.setValue(attributedOk, forKey: "titleTextFont")
            
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Ok", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: nil))
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want to set the custom font for the alert title, message and button.

Comment: After a long session of research, there doesn't seem to be anything documented online about customizing the font of the OK button itself.

Comment: From Apple's docs: **Important** *The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and doesn’t support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.* ... If you want custom fonts, design your own view.

Comment: Thank you guys :) so I need to design custom view for alert.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I'll try that for my later projects